# How to search whole words in a string that has delimiter ";"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql

I have a column that has values like this `'Blood work;MRI;ICC'`, which can be a string with some words separated by `';'`.

I wonder with a `like` clause, how can I make a query that returns results that when you search by `'Blood work'`, `'mri'`, `'icc'` but not by `'blood'` or `'mr'` or `'ic'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for a field in a CSV list, one method is:

```
where ';' + mycol + ';' like '%;mri;%'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f70e71d690781190e48193ffcaa6f112)**:

```
with 
    csv as (select 'Blood work;MRI;ICC' v),
    match as (select 'mri' m union all select 'Blood work' union all select 'Blood')
select csv.v, match.m,
    case when ';' + csv.v + ';' like '%;' + match.m + ';%' 
        then 'match' 
        else 'no match' 
    end matched
from csv
cross join match
```

```
v                  | m          | matched 
:----------------- | :--------- | :-------
Blood work;MRI;ICC | mri        | match   
Blood work;MRI;ICC | Blood work | match   
Blood work;MRI;ICC | Blood      | no match
```

Comment: Great! This works perfect. Thank you! I also thank you for editing my question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a string splitter:

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (YT.YourColumn,';') SS
WHERE SS.[Value] = 'mri';
```

If you're not using SQL Sevrer 2016+, then you can use a custom splitter, like [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this on one of our sql server 2016 instances.